# How to avoid (R CMD checks) warnings about undocumented objects when reexporting a symbol?

Tags: r, package

Suppose you have a R package **A** that exports a function **f**.
Then a package **B** that imports **f** from A, and exports it.
More precisely, the NAMESPACE file of B looks like:

```
importFrom(A, f)
export(f)
```

The problem is that when doing a R CMD check of package B (with R-3.0.1) you get:

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  ‘f’
```

How to avoid this without duplicating the documentation for A::f ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to document it - see recent discussions on R help.

Comment: Thx Hadley.  That might be a job for roxygen3 ;-)